# Unable to scroll to bottom of the page in a dynamic loading web page using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, scroll

I am unable to scroll to the bottom of the page, the problem is if we have 300 of records in a page, initially it will load only the first 15 sets of records and if the user scrolls down it loads another 15 sets of records and the process goes on.

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

I have tried the possible options but nothing works.

Your suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solution

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,500)");
```

or else you can also use robot class to scroll down

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
```

**Scrolling down multiple times :**

```
scrolls = 2
 while True:
     scrolls -= 1
     driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
     time.sleep(3)
     if scrolls < 0:
         break
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have used the robot class, action class also , but the page is scrolling down only once

Comment: Becasuse you have press button only once. you can press and release it multiple times as per your need

Comment: I have tried page down multiple time by using while loop,here i am trying to identify a Home option at the bottom of the page, and if it is displayed it should come out of the loop ,  but instead it is going for a infinite loop, any suggestion.
`while(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Home')]")).isDisplayed()) {
basePage.userClick(log, eleOutsideOfFields);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
}`

Comment: please share yur url will check from my end

Comment: Sorry it wont work outside of our server it is in development

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer if your issue is resolved